# Avoiding detection of a Default camera,in multiple cam mode

Tags: c++, opencv

I can load multiple camera feed just fine in opencv,what i want to do is set auto detection for total number of cameras connected.i use the code (part)

```
         VideoCapture cap1(CV_CAP_DSHOW + 0); 
         cap1.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,305);
         cap1.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,265);
         if(cap1.isOpened())  
         ++cam_total;  

         VideoCapture cap2(CV_CAP_DSHOW + 1);
          cap2.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,305);
         cap2.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,265);
         if(cap2.isOpened())  
         ++cam_total;


        VideoCapture cap3(CV_CAP_DSHOW + 2); // 
          cap3.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,305);
         cap3.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,265);
         if(cap3.isOpened())  
         ++cam_total;
```

now if i have three cam connected to pc,it will give me three distinct  video outputs.BUT if i have 2 cams connected then i will show the first two output fine and the third will repeat the default cam 0 (and increment cam_total). How do i avoid detecting the default cam  thus skipping the  increment  for third cam and cam_total. Dont worry about  empty frame going to any function bcoz i have set a few checks for that...Thank u